# Какая из архитектур щадяще по нагрузке MySQL

Tags: mysql, memory

Есть база под инет-магаз, более 10000 товаров.

Есть таблица, посвященная продуктам, где указаны id, название, код и т.д., всего 32 ячейки.

Хочу добавить еще функционал товаров "замена" и "схожие по характеристикам", как лучше организовать, в туже таблицу products забить или лучше создать отдельную, где ассоциировать с id товаров? Что меньше грузит базы данных?

Comment: *Хочу добавить еще функционал товаров "замена" и "схожие по характеристикам"* Это один функционал или два похожих? *как лучше* Много-ко-много никогда не следует реализовывать без таблицы связей. *Что меньше грузит базы данных?* Об этом думать ещё слишком рано.

Comment: Один скорее, тк. они к одному товару будут относиться, как поля типа double просто Id товара вводить туда.

Comment: *поля типа double* Почему double, а не, к примеру, bigint? *Один скорее, тк. они к одному товару будут относиться* Я бы ввёл две таблицы: 1) группы схожих товаров; 2) связь товар-группа. Впрочем, поскольку группы виртуальны - возможно, таблица групп и не нужна.

Comment: _Почему double, а не, к примеру, bigint_ почитаю (я в этом не особо, думал всевремя, что double меньше байт занимает).  _Я бы ввёл две таблицы_ ага, спасибо. так и попробую!

Comment: @A.Richard doble это не точный тип. вы можете записать в него одно значение, а запишется чуть чуть другое ибо в точности такое в этом типе хранить невозможно, типа 9.999999999 вместо просто 10. для id следует использовать только целочисленные типы

Comment: 10 тысяч товаров - это вообще ни о чем. Я делал 14 тысяч на WordPress - WooCommerce. Без проблем (при всех накладных расходах WC и тяжелой красивой темы).

Comment: @Mike так у меня просто под ID товаров. там ничего и не надо другого.

Comment: @KAGG Design WP не причем. Вопрос о таблице, в моем самописном аматорском решении) У вордпреса, да, видел, там создаются куча таблиц и потом сводятся еще третьей в ассоциирование. И да, там от сервера тоже многое зависит, но зачем так гробить ресурсы, у меня цель наоборот, их экономить

Comment: Я говорю о том, что даже на WP + WC 10 тыс товаров не вопрос. Так что в вашем случае экономия ресурсов не очень актуальная тема.

Comment: @KAGG Design понял, спасибо) но всеравно заморачиваюсь с байтами)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте две отдельные таблицы "замена" и "схожие по характеристикам". В них храните только id товаров и id продуктов-замен/схожих товаров. На колонку товара-источника (на тот товар, с которым будет идти сравнение) ставьте индекс. Далее при запросе вы обращаетесь к одной из этих таблиц, после чего по найденным product_id делаете запрос в основную базу с товарами.

Comment: спасибо. так и сделаю